# How to compile go program in 1.1.2 with dependencies compiled in 1.1.1?

Tags: compilation, go, upgrade

Every time I try to compile my program after (this morning) upgrading go from 1.1.1 to 1.1.2 (on Windows 7 64 bits), I get error message like:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src\github.com\spf13\hugo>go build -o hugo.exe main.go
# github.com/spf13/hugo/hugolib
hugolib\page.go:23: import C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\pkg\windows_amd64/github.com/emicklei/hopwatch.a: 
  object is [windows amd64 go1.1.1 X:none] 
  expected [windows amd64 go1.1.2 X:none]
```

I tried a `go clean -r`, but the error message persists?

What is the right `clean` command to use?

Comment: I'm surprised as the Go build system is supposed to figure out any obsolete stuff in $GOPATH/pkg and (transitively) rebuild it on demand.

Comment: @jnml I agree. It missed the dependencies, but maybe because I didn't used `go build -a` initially?

Comment: @jnml got it. I found the inconsistency in my go setup which triggered that error message. I have edited my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual solution:

I reproduced the issue with:

- calling the 1.1.2 `go.exe` directly (I didn't have `%GOROOT%\bin` in my path)
- with `GOROOT` pointing to the previous 1.1.1 installation folder (I kept go 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 installed in separated folders).

If you are sticking with the default go setup (ie: *one* `C:\go` installation directory, and `%GOROOT%\bin` in your `PATH`), you won't see this error.

But if you do see this error:

- make sure `%GOROOT%` is consistent with the `go.exe` you are calling
- `go install -a` as explained below. The `go clean` mentioned below won't be necessary.
  As [jnml](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065241/jnml) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204545/how-to-compile-go-program-in-1-1-2-with-dependencies-compiled-in-1-1-1/18204546#comment26680880_18204545):

> the Go build system is supposed to figure out any obsolete stuff in `$GOPATH/pkg` and (transitively) rebuild it on demand.

---

Original solution:

In the "**Remove object files**" section of "[Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)" page, I missed the `go clean -i` option:

```
-i
```

> The `-i` flag causes clean to remove the corresponding installed archive or binary (what 'go install' would create).

And those `.a` file (like hopwatch.a) are precisely what go install generates for libraries (in Windows).

So the full clean command, to make sure go rebuild everything, would be:

```
cd C:\Users\VonC\prog\go\src\github.com\spf13\hugo
go clean -r -i
go install -a
```

That will rebuild and install everything, including all dependent packages.

The `-a` is actually a build option, which forces rebuilding of packages that are already up-to-date.

---

As usual, `go clean -r -n` would *show* you what would be cleaned (`-n`: preview option).
It doesn't hurt to be sure of what will be deleted... before actually deleting anything.